# permutation in python: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to generate permutation numbers using code I adapted from functioning C++. The Python version errs with

```
Line 42: RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

for the input `[5,4,6,2]`.

```
class Solution:
    # @param {integer[]} nums
    # @return {integer[][]}
    def permute(self, nums):
        result = []

        if len(nums) == 0:
            return result

        if len(nums) == 1:
            result.append(nums)
            return result

        if len(nums) == 2:
            result.append(nums)
            a = nums[0]
            b = nums[1]
            newrow = [b,a]
            result.append(newrow)
            return result

        for i in range(0, len(nums)):
            temp = nums
            fixvalue = temp[i]
            del(temp[i])
            tempresult = self.permute(temp)

            for j in range(0, len(tempresult)):
                tempresult[j].insert(0,fixvalue)
                result.append(tempresult[j])

        return result
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for input `[1, 2, 3]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recursion is actually *adding* elements to the list through the line

```
tempresult[j].insert(0,fixvalue)
```

You need to change the line

```
temp = nums
```

to

```
temp = nums[:]
```

This will create a *copy* of the input [using copy-by-slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python). Your present code is manipulating the original.

---

Unrelatedly, I'm not sure at all why you have a Java-esque *class* `Solution` containing `permute` without any state at all. Why not simply use `permute` as a function? What does the class add?

Comment: thanks, you are right. after changing that line, the program works!

Answer (score 2):

The logic of your code has several errors regarding its manipulation of the lists. I'm actually a bit surprised by the error you're getting, as I would have thought an `IndexError` would be more likely, but it turns out you're adding new values to your lists as often as you're removing them.

Here's the core of the error:

```
temp = nums
```

This doesn't do what you expect if you're coming from C or C++. It doesn't copy the list stored in the `nums` variable and store the copied data as `temp`. It just creates a reference to the same list object. When you later modify `temp` (with `del`, and in some confusing corner cases, with `insert`), you're modifying `nums` as well.

You should think of assignments in Python as being like pointer assignments in C. Two pointers can refer to the same point in memory, and modifying that memory through one of them will affect what you see when you read the memory through the other pointer.

As for how to solve the issue, you will probably have better luck if you copy the contents of your `nums` list in some way. You can either use `list` or a slice `nums[:]` to copy the whole thing before using `del` to modify the copy, or you could use two smaller slices to get the values you want directly (`nums[:i] + nums[i+1:]`).

Answer (score 0):

If you just need permutations, python provides a out-of-box solution in `itertools.permutations`.

If you want to do this as an exercise, there are several problems with your code:

- You have to make a copy of the list before recursion
- Your recursion algorithm needs a special case for empty list, or list with one item, otherwise it won't exit, hence the recursion limit is exceeded.

If you correct your algorithm, and it still exceeds the recursion limit, you can change the recursion limit (default 1000) with:

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
```

My suggestion is to take a look at the [official implementation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) in itertools.